# Accessing SSH of a device connected on a separate interface (Ubuntu)

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager

I've got the following network setup:

Windows PC <-ethernet-> Odroid XU4 <- USB Ethernet-> nVidia Jetson

I would like to be able to have network access from the Windows PC to Odroid (SSH) and Jetson (SSH, RTSP stream). I would also like for the Odroid and Jetson to communicate (Jetson).

How can I go about doing this? I've been doing some searching, and it looks like bridging on the Odroid might be the solution, but I'm not sure. I've tried it once or twice following some guides and I could not establish a connection.

Any help appreciated, thanks!